# MVC script bundling optimization results in huge server load

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

Using:

- MVC 5.2.0.0
- Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization 1.1.3
- Visual Studio 13
- latest updates as of this writing

My Host service was resetting my app pool because I ran over limits. Their limits are 300 MB per Post or Get. That seemed like enough! So what's going on? I used Fiddler to find out that bundling is causing me a major headache.

If I use the script loading in the Layouts:

```
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js")"></script>
```

etc, using Fiddler, I see my page loads with about 55K of scripts, for everything I need to run with.

If I use:

```
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

etc, Fiddler reports a 7 MB load just for *one* bundle, and it goes down hill fast from there...

The data for the scripts is a garbled mess of characters, so it looks like optimization is encrypting all scripts that are bundled.

I like the ease of use of bundling, but is there a way to turn off this sort of 'packaging'? All I want from bundling is to help organize my scripts into blocks so I don't need to have to copy so much around to each Layout file.

**Edit:**

Sorry, the 300 MB is memory limit in the app pool. That's what I'm bumping up against.

The bundle, is standard fare stuff (instead of multiple bundles being called, I stuff it all into one).:

```
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*",
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*",
                    "~/Scripts/site.js",
                    "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                    "~/Scripts/respond.js",
                    "~/Scripts/masonry.pkgd.min.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.zoom.min.js",
                    "~/Scripts/AnimOnScroll.js",
                    "~/Scripts/classie.js",
                    "~/Scripts/imagesloaded.js",
                    "~/Scripts/util.js"));
```

Also - this is not my server - it's a hosting service: DiscountASP.net

**Another Edit**

Sorry the amount is 550K vs 7 MB

Comment: Please post your bundle config.

Comment: There's no such thing as "encrypting" assets.. the browser has to read them, if they're encrypted that can't work.  You might have your server configured to gzip them, which would make them binary.  I'm also confused by your wording of "load" and "limits".  Are you talking about memory? or bandwidth?  If bandwidth, 300mb is not much at all... even for a simple site... and you will burn through that in no time...

Comment: Also, check your jquery bundle, this typically includes more than just jquery.

Comment: How exactly does Fiddler relate to how much memory you're using?  And how do you know that Bundling is causing your memory problems?  Your question includes no evidence linking the two.

Comment: Fiddler doesn't relate to anything - it just reports the amount of stuff I pull from the server. Bundle = 7Mb no bundle = 55K

Comment: Because no bundle is only including jQuery, while your bundle includes 11 other js files, what are the sizes of those files?

Comment: Yes, I typically include everything in one bundle unless I specifically don't want to use some aspects of my js lib; for example my landing page vs. my shopping cart.

Comment: So I don't understand your point in complaining that it's only 55k when you include just jQuery...

Comment: those files are all small - modernizer is like 55 k - respond 8 K - bootstrap 55 k, anim is 6K - oh! looks like the total I'm reading is 550K vs 7 MB! yikes

Comment: no - what I'm complaining about is when I include the same set of files, with bundle, the browser pulls 7 MB of data from the server vs 550 K if I don't use bundling

Comment: if DiscountASP.net was gzipping stuff, wouldn't that make it smaller? This is 12.5 times the size, just for using bundling...

Comment: I'll capture the Fiddler session for you to help understand

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code in your BundleConfig.cs to disable the optimization step of minifying:

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
```

Instead what you will be left with is the output of all the scripts the bundle collected before consolidation.

Then you can view where the issue is being caused if too many scripts are being bundled together or duplicates are being added because of your "*" wildcard scripts.